# SqlCommand not sending `EXEC @return = Sproc` when `ReturnValue` is set

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, ado.net

I have a SQL Server stored procedure which returns multiple result tables in addition to also always returning an integer value, e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Foo
    @someParameter varchar(100) = NULL,
    @anotherParam  date
AS
BEGIN
    IF @anotherParam > GETDATE() BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END

    SELECT foo, bar FROM someTable    WHERE blargh
    SELECT baz      FROM anotherTable WHERE blargh

    RETURN 0
END
```

In C# I'm doing this:

```
using( DbCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand() ) {
    // cmd is an instance of SqlCommand despite being cast to DbCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "Foo";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    /* code that adds other parameters here */

    IDataParameter returnParam = cmd.CreateParameter(); // returnParam is an instance of SqlParameter
    returnParam.ParameterName = "@ReturnValue";
    returnParam.Direction     = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    returnParam.DbType        = DbType.Int32;
    cmd.Parameters.Add( paraReturn );

    using( DbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader() ) {
        Int32 returnValue = (Int32)returnParam.Value; <-- exception here
    }
}
```

SQL Server Profiler shows that the following command is sent to the server:

```
exec Foo @someParameter=N'1234ABCD',@anotherParam='2015-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Nowhere does it add the `@ReturnValue` parameter to capture the sproc's return value.

In contrast, when I use SQL Server Management Studio to execute the procedure, the Profiler shows that this is sent to the server:

```
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC @return_value = Foo @someParameter=N'1234ABCD',@anotherParam='2015-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, it turns out that the return-value from a sproc *is* returned: it is "emitted" anonymously from SQL Server without needing an explicit variable to capture it (though you can still capture it if necessary, as in the SQL Server Management Studio example I gave).

So while the return-value is there, the `DbDataReader` won't populate the `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` parameter **until** the reader has been closed.

So this works:

```
IDataParameter returnParam = cmd.CreateParameter(); // returnParam is an instance of SqlParameter
returnParam.ParameterName = "@ReturnValue";
returnParam.Direction     = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
returnParam.DbType        = DbType.Int32;
cmd.Parameters.Add( paraReturn );

using( DbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader() ) {
    // do stuff
}
Int32 returnValue = (Int32)returnParam.Value;
```

but this doesn't:

```
...
using( DbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader() ) {
    Int32 returnValue = (Int32)returnParam.Value;
}
```

Comment: Great that you found this... I did never try this, because I try to avoid SPs and rather use TVFs. My answer is deleted as it was wrong... +1 from my side

Comment: @Shnugo I needed to use a sproc because I need to return multiple tables at once.